# iMessage can't save photos

Tags: photos, high-sierra, error

Sometimes when I try to save photos received in iMessage, the following error or something similar appears. The error changes even between attempts on the same pictures.

[image: Error received while trying to save attachments]

Comment: Did you try a right-click on photo and then click open?

Comment: Yes, I can open the photo that way however, I should be able to save by right-clicking and then selecting Add To Photos Library.  For some reason certain photos (by different people) produce an error.